# Is a board with on-board radio disabled an unintentional/intentional radiator?

Tags: rf, fcc

If a board with the onboard radio (e.g., Bluetooth) chip disabled by software using a jumper, would it be considered to be an intentional or unintentional radiator? That is, the onboard radio can be enabled by flipping a jumper but is disabled in default settings on arrival.

Comment: If your trying to get around FCC requirements for testing, you're in for a shocking legal bill down the road.

Comment: If it is essentially impossible for the end user to enable the radio you might get away with it. Otherwise, probably not. Can you explain the motivation for doing this? Wouldn't it be cheaper to make the device without the blue-tooth components instead of just disabling them?

Comment: @mkeith Basically the current design failed certification. We haven't got time for a redesign so we were thinking if we could ship the first few batches using the current design but with the radio switched off using a jumper. Later on, we'll fix the interference and re-enable the radio.

Comment: If your product for some reason has a radio which is always disabled, I think you will be fine, as long as there are no easy way for the users to enable it.

Comment: @Lundin But what makes a method too easy for the user? I guess a jumper would be easier than shorting solder pads. But if the switch is done in the firmware, would that be too easy still?

Comment: @Kar I think the key is that they shouldn't be able to activate the radio by accident. Suppose for example that there are other jumpers nearby and they put one in the wrong place. A solution with solder pads is definitely better. Or a zero ohm resistor which is not mounted.

Comment: If the user had to open up a case in order to reconfigure the jumper in order to activate the radio, would that be challenging enough for it to be considered as an unintentional radiator?

Comment: Not sure, but the harder it is, the better. If they have to open the case, that seems like a real barrier to me. Your intent also would matter to the FCC (assuming you are in the US). If you are trying to give people an easy way to activate devices that do not pass, the FCC may punish you more harshly (recall). If you act in good faith, then they are more likely to be sympathetic (waiver and corrective action). So I have heard. I have never had to deal with a non-compliance situation.